# Sieve of Atkins, unexpected results

Tags: java

So I am working on the Sieve of Atkins for Problem 10.

Question:

"The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.

Find the sum of all the primes below two million."

I believe I am following the steps correctly but it's failing to give the right answer.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class Level_10 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Sieve of atkins
        int limit = 2000000;
        long sum = 0;
        int ins = 2;
        int limitsq = ((int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(limit)));
        ArrayList<Long> results = new ArrayList<Long>();
        //2, 3. and 5 are primes
        results.add(2L);
        results.add(3L);
        results.add(5L);
        Map<Long, Boolean> sieves = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>(); //composite list
        //adding sieves
        for (int i = 5; i <= limit; i++) sieves.put((long) i,false);

    long n;
    for (int x = 1; x < limitsq; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < limitsq; y++) {
            //4x^2 + y^2
            n = ((4*(x*x)) + (y*y));
            if (n <= limit && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5)) sieves.put(n*n, true);
            //3x^2 + y^2
            n = ((3*(x*x)) + (y*y));
            if (n <= limit && (n % 12 == 7)) sieves.put(n*n, true);
            //3x^2 − y^2
            n = ((3*(x*x)) - (y*y));
            if (x > y && n <= limit && (n % 12 == 11)) sieves.put(n*n, true);

        }
    }

    //Multiple of squares are not prime
    for (int num = 1; num < limitsq; num++) {
        if (sieves.get(num) != null) for (int m = num * num; m <= limit; m += num * num) sieves.put((long) m, false);
    }

    //Add into results

        for (Entry<Long, Boolean> nextSieve : sieves.entrySet()) {
        if (nextSieve.getValue() && ins % 2 == 0) {
            results.add(nextSieve.getKey());
            ins++;
        }
    }
    //Generate the sum
    for (Long resultNum : results) sum += resultNum;

    System.out.println("The sum of all primes below " + limit + " is " + sum);

     }
}
```

If anything here is inefficient, please notify me.

Comment: Sieve of Atkins? Is that the sieve which doesn't use any carbohydrates?

Comment: System.out.println() is your friend to find the place where in the code reality and what you believe reality is stop being the same. You'll have to print out the intermediate results of the calculations you're doing and try to spot where it goes wrong. When you figure out where it happens you can continue to answering WHY it happens there.

Comment: Does it give the right answer (17) when you set the limit to 10?

Comment: @TedHopp It gives me 59 when I set the limit to 10. I'll follow Gimby's advice though.

Comment: Just a tip for efficiency on ur last for loop, adding num*num to m everytime means it has to calculate num*num everytime.
I'd suggest you use: for(int m = 1; m*(num*num)<=limit; m++)
And preferably compute num*num into an int and use the int instead for more speed to the cost of memory.
Also I can't seem to find an error in the algorithm, so you have to do what gimby said, use a println() method everytime an index in your sieve map is being set to true and check manually if it agrees with your code.